# SelectList com ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando fazer uma `SelectList` usando `ViewBag`. Porém quando executo meu código ele mostra de onde a informação que estou tentando acessar é, por exemplo:

```
NomeProjeto.Models.NomeModel
```

Estou usando o seguinte código em meu `Controller`:

```
var setores = new List<Setor>();

using (RamaDb db = new RamaDb())
{
     setores = db.Setores.ToList();
}

ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(setores, "setorNome");
```

E esse em minha `View`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.setores, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ID)
```

Quando executo a aplicação na `SelectList` aparece o número de Setores corretamente, tipo tenho 3 setores em minha DB então aparece 3 opções, porém em todas está escrito ***RamalAguia.Models.Setor***

Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

faltou colocar o campo que irá aparecer, vc só colocou o ID, altere a linha:

```
ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(setores, "setorNome");
```

para

```
ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(setores, "setorID","setorNome");
```

Se quiser enviar qual vai estar selecionado é o 4º campo, ex:

```
 ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(setores, "setorID","setorNome", 4);
```

onde 4 seria o setorID selected

Comment: Na verdade o "setorNome" já era o nome, e eu tinha o "setorID" mas pensei que só deveria colocar se eu quisesse que ele aparecesse. Mas mesmo assim eu entendi sua resposta e realmente funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda. Só não vou subir sua resposta porque não tenho reputação.

Comment: o primeiro é ID o segundo é o texto vou editar a resposta para ficar com os campos corretores